# How to interleave two matrices in numpy without copying values?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

In `pygame` I'd like to interleave two surfaces before displaying them on screen so that:

1. Odd numbered lines contain pixels from surface A,
2. Even numbered lines contain pixels from surface B.

In `pygame` docs they say this is more efficient to do with `pixelArray`, which is Surface represented as `numpy` array. I did this by copying data into a new array, but the result is still very slow.

Is there a more efficient way to do this (I suppose using some `numpy` method) so pixel data is accessed in original matrices, without copying every pixel?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861436/2529026

Comment: David's reference shows some fast ways of doing the copy, but it is still copying.

Comment: The basic answer is no; the data of the new array must be a copy of the source arrays.  From the related sidebar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005735/list-of-numpy-arrays-to-single-numpy-array-without-copying-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773918/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-soft-reference-or-pointer-like-objects-using-numpy-ar

Comment: Although it's not possible to interleave two pre-existing arrays without copying, what you could do is allocate your output array, then fill alternating row slices with the pixel data for A and B.