# Matrices generation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to generate a matrix from two other matrices in python. So what I'd like to do is to consider the first row from the first matrix and place it into the new matrix, and then the same but from the second matrix. The next step would be moving to the second rows of both matrices, and so on.

Inputs:

```
A = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5 ,5 ,5, 5]]

B = [[6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7 ,7 ,7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Should produce the output:

```
C = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6,], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8] ... [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

If possibly I don't want to use any loops.

Comment: This isn't valid Python syntax. What's the input? What's the desired output? What have you tried? Why don't you want loops?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like matlab. Do you mean matlab?

Comment: Yes, I know, was just giving an example. As can be seen from the example itself, the 'inputs' will be the two matrices A and B generated using numpy.matrix and the desired output is matrix C. To be honest I'm new to python so haven't tried much. What i've tried though is something like this:

C = A[0::1],B[0::1]

The reason for no loops is just to have it as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in numpy like so:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5 ,5 ,5, 5]])

B = np.array([[6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7 ,7 ,7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

print np.hstack((A, B)).reshape((-1, A.shape[1]))
```

Note that I've made the syntax valid for creating arrays.

This produces:

```
 [[1 1 1 1 1]
 [6 6 6 6 6]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [7 7 7 7 7]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [8 8 8 8 8]
 [4 4 4 4 4]
 [9 9 9 9 9]
 [5 5 5 5 5]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

What's happening here is that `np.hstack` creates an intermediate array like so:

```
print np.hstack((A, B))

[[1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6]
 [2 2 2 2 2 7 7 7 7 7]
 [3 3 3 3 3 8 8 8 8 8]
 [4 4 4 4 4 9 9 9 9 9]
 [5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

This is the horizontal concatentation of `A` and `B`.

Now, I [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) this into the final matrix using `.reshape((-1, A.shape[1]))`. Because numpy arrays are by default in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), each pair of adjacient rows in the final array is formed from one row of this intermediate array.

(See also solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12861314/279858))

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. One minor problem is that the list object won't have the attribute shape. What can be done about that?

Comment: This code will all work. At the end you will have numpy arrays rather than lists. Note that I convert the python lists to numpy arrays --- this is an important step!

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to use vsplit to split my matrix and thats why it didn't work.