# Stacking multiple 2d arrays by picking 1 column from each of the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack

I have 3 numpy arrays of dimensions 20x308 each. I want to stack them so that i have the first column from 1st array, 1st column from  2nd array, 1st from 3rd and then 2nd from each and so on so that i will end up with 20x924 array. I have tried by looking at np.column_stack but that won't work. Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interleave rows of two numpy arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861314/interleave-rows-of-two-numpy-arrays-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution now, by using dstack and reshape.

```
    a = np.ones((2,3))
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    d = [[1,3,5], [2,5,9]]
    c = np.dstack([a, b,d]).reshape(2,9)
```